# fwrite 4 char array, would write 7 instead of 4

Tags: c++, windows, fwrite

The source code:

```
 main(void) {
  unsigned char tmp[5] = {10, 10, 180, 255, 40};
  FILE *ff = fopen("aa.bin", "w");
  fwrite(&tmp, sizeof(char), 5, ff);
}
```

When executed and seeing Hex content of the file aa.bin, it looks like this:

> 0D 0A 0D 0A B4 FF 28

Why the value of 10 is written in two bytes (0D 0A) and char type holds only 1 byte. and what does (0D) means?

I am using G++ compiler (MinGW on Windows) and cpp11.

Comment: 1) This is C not C++, 2) Hex of `10` is `A` 3) Try `FILE *ff = fopen("aa.bin", "wb");` if you wish to write in binary mode.

Comment: `&tmp` should be either `tmp` or `&tmp[0]`

Comment: Thanks @DimChtz , works now... Going to search more for the "b" flag.

Comment: @OsamaSaadallahAl-Ta'ai `b` flag means binary mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is fwrite writing more than I tell it to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586421/why-is-fwrite-writing-more-than-i-tell-it-to)

Comment: (funnily, that one is also mistagged, but in the other direction)

Comment: Also [edit] your question to add the tag [tag:windows].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ASCII, 10 is the character code for the newline `'\n'`.

Since you are operating in non-binary mode, the newline is interpreted as an actual newline and the standard library converts it to the platform-specific newline sequence, which is, on Windows systems, CR-LF (carriage return and line feed) or `0D 0A` in hexadecimal.

Try to open the file in binary mode to skip the higher-level interpretation of the standard library and simply operate on bytes, not characters. Use `"wb"` for that purpose instead of `"w"`.

---

As an aside, use `tmp` instead of `&tmp`. An array is implicitly converted to a pointer in certain situations, including the one at hand, it *decays*. `&tmp` is an actual pointer to an array, an `unsigned char (*)[5]` in this case. While both are equivalent in your specific case, this can turn problematic.